# Javascript function do not running on every modals i call

Tags: javascript, php

I have a data that i show in page using while loop. When I click on the blue button "beli", the modal will show. Like this:

[image]

I use javascript function to automatically count like on the image 2x12000 = 24.000 and show the result (24.000) on the textbox, beside label "total real". it is running well on the first data. But when I do it on the next data, modal show but javascript function is not automatically count like as I said before.

This is the javascript function :

```
<script>
   function myFunction(val) {
    var a = document.getElementById("txt").value  * val;
    document.getElementById("txtreal").value = a;
   }
</script>
<script>
   function myFunctio(val) {
    var a =  document.getElementById("txtjumlah").value * val;
    document.getElementById("txtp").value = a;
   }
</script>
```

and it is called on the while loop :

```
while(){



   // the modal here, and i call the function above.

}
```

like this :

```
<?php
   while(($count<$rpp) && ($i<$tcount)) {
   mysqli_data_seek($result,$i);
   $r = mysqli_fetch_array($result); ?>
<div class="col-md-6" style="border:0px solid #bbb;border-radius:30px;padding:0px 20px 10px 20px;">
   <div class="thumbnail">
      <?php     $s= " 
         SELECT * FROM tbbarang where idbarang='$r[idbarang]' ";


                    $resu = mysqli_query($koneksi,$s);
                while  ($d= mysqli_fetch_array($resu)){

                    ?>        
      <img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()"   src="<?php echo $d['gmbr1'] ?>">
      <script>
         function changeImage() {
             var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
             if (image.src.match("<?php echo $d['gmbr4'] ?>"))
             {
                 image.src = "<?php echo $d['gmbr1'] ?>"; 


             } 
            else if (image.src.match("<?php echo $d['gmbr1'] ?>"))
                {
                  image.src = "<?php echo $d['gmbr2'] ?>"; 

                }
            else if (image.src.match("<?php echo $d['gmbr2'] ?>"))
                {
                  image.src = "<?php echo $d['gmbr3'] ?>"; 

                }

            else if (image.src.match("<?php echo $d['gmbr3'] ?>"))
            {
                  image.src = "<?php echo $d['gmbr4'] ?>";


                }   
         }
         <?php } ?>
      </script>                                                    
      <div class="caption">
         <h3><b><?php echo  $r['namabarang']; ?></b></h3>
         <tr style="font-size:14px;"><strong>Harga : <?php echo  $r['harga']; ?> </strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;  Satuan : <?php echo  $r['satuan']; ?>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;                                                          
         </tr>
         <tr style="font-size:14px;">Ukuran : <?php echo  $r['ukuran']; ?> &nbsp;&nbsp; Berat : <?php echo  $r['berat']; ?></tr>
         <p>
            <a  data-toggle="modal" href="#responsive<?php echo  $i; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Beli </a>
            <!-- Modal -->
            <!-- mulai modal -->
         </p>
         <div id="responsive<?php echo  $i; ?>" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" align="center" >
            <form method="POST" action="inserttransaksi.php">
               <div class="modal-dialog" align="center">
                  <div class="modal-content" align="center">
                     <div class="modal-header" align="center">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title"><strong>Detail Pembelian</strong></h4>
                     </div>
                     <div class="modal-body" align="center">
                        <div class="scroller" style="height:200px" data-always-visible="1" data-rail-visible1="1" align="center">
                           <div class="row" align="center">
                              <div class="table col-md-6" align="center">
                                 <!--h4 align="center"><strong>Keterangan Cancel Barang <?php echo $r['namabarang'];?></strong></h4-->
                                 <table width="612" height="156">
                                    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $r['idbarang'];?>" name="iddetail2" class="input-xsmall" ></td> 
                                    <?php $sq= "SELECT * FROM tbbarang where idbarang='$r[idbarang]'";
                                       $resul = mysqli_query($koneksi,$sq);
                                       $s= mysqli_fetch_array($resul);

                                       ?>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td width="91" height="36">Nama Barang</td>
                                       <td width="6">: &nbsp;</td>
                                       <td width="168"><strong><?php echo $r['namabarang'];?></strong></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td height="23">Jumlah</td>
                                       <td>:&nbsp;</td>
                                       <input  value="<?php echo $s['harga'];?>" name="txt" id="txt" class="form-control" type="text"></td> 
                                       <td><input type="text" value="" name="txtjumlah" id="txtjumlah" class="input-xsmall" onKeyUp="myFunction(this.value)"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td height="41">Harga</td>
                                       <td>:&nbsp;</td>
                                       <td><?php echo $s['harga'];?></td>
                                       <td width="18">&nbsp;</td>
                                       <td width="123" height="41">Total Real</td>
                                       <td width="6">:&nbsp;</td>
                                       <td width="168"><input type="text" value="" name="txtreal" id="txtreal" class="form-control" readonly></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>&nbsp;</tr>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td height="31">Penawaran</td>
                                       <td>:&nbsp;</td>
                                       <td><input type="text" value="" name="txtpe" id="txtpe" class="form-control" onKeyUp="myFunctio(this.value)"></td>
                                       <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                       <td height="32">Total Penawaran</td>
                                       <td>:</td>
                                       <td><input type="text" value="" name="txtp" id="txtp" class="form-control" readonly></td>
                                    </tr>
                                 </table>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                           <button type="submit" name="save1" class="btn default">Save</button>
                           <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn default">Close</button>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </form>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<?php
   $i++; 
   $count++;
   }
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
   function myFunction(id, val) {
    var a = document.getElementById("txt"+id).value  * val;
    document.getElementById("txtreal"+id).value = a;
   }
</script>
<script>
   function myFunctio(id, val) {
    var a =  document.getElementById("txtjumlah"+id).value * val;
    document.getElementById("txtp"+id).value = a;
   }
</script>  

...
<td><input type="text" value="" name="txtjumlah<?php echo $i;?>" id="txtjumlah<?php echo $i;?>" class="input-xsmall" onKeyUp="myFunction(<?php echo $i;?>, this.value)"></td>
...
<td><input type="text" value="" name="txtpe<?php echo $i;?>" id="txtpe<?php echo $i;?>" class="form-control" onKeyUp="myFunctio(<?php echo $i;?>,this.value)"></td>
...
```

`id` should be unique on page